Using Ffmpeg to concatenate a JPG image with an MP4 clip
I would like to concatenate a JPG image with an MP4 clip (Windows 10). The image must play silently for the first 5 seconds of the resulting clip, then the original video must follow. The JPG needs to be scaled to match the clip resolution, original clip's framerate and resolution must remain unchanged. I would like to do it without re-encoding the video, since I have a 100+ clips to process:
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 5 -i %1.jpg -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc -i %1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][2:v]scale2ref[logo][video]; [logo]setsar=sar=1[logo]; [logo][1:a][video][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" %1-output.mp4
However, the ffmpeg is stuck on frame 69 and not advancing. If I terminate the program, I end up with 5 secs of image and a few frames of the source auio/video as a result. What am I doing wrong?
p.s. Ffmpeg is the latest version.


What are you setting the image to be 5 seconds for if the intention is to set the image to be only one frame of video? Also you didn't set a limit for the audio (anullsrc) length so I guess that causes ffmpeg to try to render infinitly...

Ye, the command above doesn't make a whole lot of sense compared to your description. Is it just copied from somewhere?

-f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc limit for the audio is set at 1 second. I did try to use the -vframes 1 parameter, but it doesn't seem to work. If I use -t 1 instead of -t 5 ffmpeg just hangs even without displaying frame progress

Found another example on superuser: ffmpeg -y -i %1.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i %1.jpg -filter_complex "[1]fade=out:st=1:d=0.9:alpha=1,trim=0:2[f]; [1]fade=st=2:d=0.5:alpha=1,trim=0:3[s]; [f][0]scale2ref[fs][video];[s][fs]scale2ref=iw/8:-1[ss][fo]; [video][fo]overlay=eof_action=pass[v0]; [v0][ss]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy %1-output.mp4
Doesn't seem to work either. Ffmpeg just hangs where it's supposed to show framecount.

That is a completely different random command. I'd suggest understanding what you want to do and finding basic filters instead of shooting in the dark with commands you don't understand or follow. Modifying audio, trimming, overlaying and fading are all unnecessary and don't fit your description. But the description is also likely wrong as I doubt you just want 1 frame to be an image, you want it to not be seen except when paused? Or do you want the video to be extremely low FPS? Or do you want to change the cover image of the video? What's the general goal here?

My question was not to help me figure out what I'm trying to achieve, but why the Ffmpeg hangs given a 100% legitimate command and params. I modified the original question. Can you help?

The issue is related to mismatching between video framerate and the framerate of the looped image (there is probably also a bug in FFmpeg 7.1).
In case we don't know the framerate, we may use tpad and overlay filters, instead of using loop and concat:
Using FFmpeg version 7.1 we may also avoid scale2ref (use scale=rw:rh instead):
ffmpeg -y -i 1.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[2:v]tpad=start_duration=5[pv];[0:v][2:v]scale=rw:rh[logo];[logo]setsar=sar=1[logo];[pv][logo]overlay=enable=between(t\,0\,5)[outv];[1:a][2:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" 1-output.mp4
Using FFmpeg version 5.1.2:
ffmpeg -y -i 1.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[2:v]tpad=start_duration=5[pv];[0:v][pv]scale2ref[logo][video];[logo]setsar=sar=1[logo];[video][logo]overlay=enable=between(t\,0\,5)[outv];[1:a][2:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" 1-output.mp4


[2:v]tpad=start_duration=5[pv] - add black frames to the beginning of the video into [pv] (the padding has the same framerate as the input video).
[0:v][2:v]scale=rw:rh[logo];[logo]setsar=sar=1[logo] - scale the logo image to the size of the video.
[video][logo]overlay=enable=between(t\,0\,5)[outv] - overlay the logo on top of the video, for the first 5 seconds (cover only the padded frames).
[2:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa] - concatenate the 5 seconds of anullsrc with the original audio.


Testing (using version 5.1.2):
Create sample input video and image:
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=100x100:r=1:d=1 -frames:v 1 -update 1 1.jpg
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=10 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=200 -acodec aac -t 30 1.mp4
Without setting the framerate, FFmpeg is stuck:
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][2:v]scale2ref[logo][video]; [logo]setsar=sar=1[logo]; [logo][1:a][video][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" 1-output.mp4
Note: the default framerate is 25fps.
When setting the framerate, it's working with FFmpeg 5.1.2 (but stuck using FFmpeg 7.1):
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 10 -t 5 -i 1.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][2:v]scale2ref[logo][video]; [logo]setsar=sar=1[logo]; [logo][1:a][video][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" 1-output.mp4

Thank you for the great explanaion, it's actually working now. However, I intended to do it without re-encoding the whole video. Is it possible? Because I have 100+ videos to process.

It should be possible, without re-encoding the video (I am not sure about the audio), but there are many problems that might occur. In the following answer, I tried to solve a similar problem (as you can see, it requires some programming). Your case may be a bit simpler, because the video starts with a keyframe, but implementing a robust solution is still challenging.

I was able to achieve this without re-encoding by breaking the task into 3 parts. 1) call ffprobe to get source video framerate/resolution 2) convert the JPG to MP4 video resizing/matching source video framerate/resolution 3) concatenating the two video files into one. However, the resulting video does not play on the target platform (Telegram mobile app), it says it's faulty, while the original video plays fine. The resulting video still plays ok on VLC, in Adobe Premiere and Telegram Desktop app. Could you please elaborate on why this could be happening?

I can't answer without a sample input file. There are many "small things" that can go wrong.
